# how do I change a viewController's supported orientation's?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview, uiinterfaceorientation

I want my UIWebView to be locked in portrait mode until the progress view is finished loading, then allow it to support all orientations.. is this possible? Here the code I attempted to use:

```
class MyWebViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var myWebView: UIWebView!

@IBOutlet var progressView: UIProgressView!

var contentUrlPassedOn: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    myWebView.delegate = self
    let url: NSURL! = NSURL(string: contentUrlPassedOn)
    myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
}
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown]
}

func updateProgress(){

    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    if progressView.progress >= 1 {

    UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All

} else {
     //...
}
```

This was unsuccessful.. Any suggestions to how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
if (UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft ||
    UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight ||
    UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Unknown) {
        return false;
}
else {
    return true;
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue) | Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown.rawValue)
}
```

Copy and paste the above code in the VC which you want in portrait mode only

Hope this helps!
Best of luck,
Suprem

Comment: that wasn't the issue at hand, I wanted it in portrait mode only until the progress finished loading..

Answer (score 0):

offcource we can controll the orientation, use the Boolean Value like `isWebViewLoaded`

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

    self.isWebViewLoaded = NO;
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    self.isWebViewLoaded = YES;
}
```

And Check the condition in Orientation method......if `self.isWebViewLoaded = YES` then allow all the Orientations `else` restrict for only portrait mode and finally reset the Boolean Value as per your requirement....

Try This Method....

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    if (self.isLoad == NO)
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    else
      return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Comment: so can you include in your code the restriction of orientations except portrait with `isWebViewLoaded = NO` and the addidtion of all orientations with `isWebViewLoaded = YES`